# ArrayList gets filled instead of replacing index java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i'm trying to replace a value in my string arraylist but my arraylist just seems to add instead of replacing.

temp is a string that takes the value from a bufferreader.
player_status_line is my string arraylist.

I cannot see what i'm doing wrong. I check the array size and if it contains the users name (getName[2]) i set the new value to the same spot.

This is what i did but somehow it still saves everything. Tried to go through the code but cannot see the problem.

Code is edited*

```
while ((checkIfPlayer = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Arraylist
    String temp = checkIfPlayer.trim();
    System.out.println(temp);
    if (temp.contains("ZOMBIE") || temp.contains("HUMAN")) {
        String[] getName = temp.split(" ");
        String checkName = getName[2];
        if (!player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
            player_status_list.add(temp);
        } else if (player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < player_status_list.size(); i++) {
                player_status_list.set(i, temp);
            }
        }
        DrawTheMap();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd put together a small test case that demonstrates the behavior. Just a main method that does a similar thing using hardcoded values and a predefined list. That way we can run the code for ourselves and see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: What does `temp` actually holds in the String as an example?

Comment: Edited my answer in response to your code change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checks are incorrect at:

```
if (!player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
    player_status_list.add(temp);
} else if (player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < player_status_list.size(); i++) {
        player_status_list.set(i, temp);
    }
}
```

Here is a breakdown with embedded comments:

```
//temp = "4711 PLAYER joseph HUMAN 30.1 30.1";
//checkName = "joseph"

//This is checking if the list contains:  "joseph"
if (!player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
    //If it doesn't have it we are adding: "4711 PLAYER joseph HUMAN 30.1 30.1";
    //This doesn't seem right!!!
    player_status_list.add(temp);

   //This will never happen because list is always adding the temp variable not the name
} else if (player_status_list.contains(checkName)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < player_status_list.size(); i++) {
        player_status_list.set(i, temp);
    }
}
```

Try the following:

```
while ((checkIfPlayer = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
    // Arraylist
    String temp = checkIfPlayer.trim();
    System.out.println(temp);
    if (temp.contains("ZOMBIE") || temp.contains("HUMAN")) {
        String[] getName = temp.split(" ");
        String checkName = getName[2];
        boolean added = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < player_status_list.size(); i++) {
            if(player_status_list.get(i).contains(checkName)) {
                player_status_list.set(i, temp);
                added = true;
            }
        }
        if(!added) {
            player_status_list.add(temp);
        }
        DrawTheMap();
    }
}
```

The inputs I tested (Obviously I commented out the DrawTheMap() part)

```
ASYNC PLAYER joseph HUMAN 30.0 30.0
ASYNC PLAYER joseph HUMAN 50.0 80.0
ASYNC PLAYER BOB ZOMBIE 30.0 30.0
ASYNC PLAYER GIL ZOMBIE 30.0 30.0
```

This is the resulting `player_status_list` I get:

```
ASYNC PLAYER joseph HUMAN 50.0 80.0
ASYNC PLAYER BOB ZOMBIE 30.0 30.0
ASYNC PLAYER GIL ZOMBIE 30.0 30.0
```

Comment: i forgot to edit my code. Did it now, cannot see what im doing wrong since it keeps adding to the arraylist.

Comment: Your Edited code won't compile `+ player_status_list);
                    player_status_list.add(temp);
                    name = false;
                }`

Comment: i changed the code a little but i still cannot understand why it don't work.

Comment: Can you provide what `String temp = checkIfPlayer.trim();` looks like an example of a String like `ZOMBIE 1 ROB` or something like that

Comment: The server sends this ASYNC PLAYER joseph HUMAN 30.0 30.0  or it sends 4711 PLAYER joseph HUMAN 30.1 30.1 depending on what i send to the server. 4711 is just an example to see how many commands the server has received since it started. So String temp is one of those above

Comment: Thank you very much gtgaxiola for your time and help! I understand why my code didn't work now.. So stupid

Comment: @JosephOlsson you are most welcome! (du är välkommen)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, first check to see IF the player_status_list.get(i)==checkName and only then replace the variable at that index with the checkName.

You can also simplify the whole code you posted by doing:

```
if !containsname
    add name
else
    find index at the name (maybe use forloop)
    replace at index with name
```

Comment: Hey, i believe i changed it the way you said was simpler but it is still adding more and mroe in the arraylist. Been doing this android app for 8 hours straight now so my head is a little out of work :P